# What am I and where can I go?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, anagram

This puzzle will reveal what I (wish) am. 
Unfortunately it doesn't exist (yet) or as far as we know!

> **V**
>   `0`    XV-II    `C`
>   `00` IV `D`
>   `0` CCCXCV
>    **E**
>   I `E` DLXVI-DLX  `A`
>   `0` XXIV `C`
>    `00` XLI
>    `0045`
>   D-CDLXXVI `D` IIX
>   XXIV `C` IX
>    **R**

**Question**: What am I and where can I go?

Clue about where can I go:

> The question what am I reveals where I can go.

Comment: Should there not be spaces around the hyphen in line 2? (below the V)

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 I see what you mean, it shouldn't matter but I removed the space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Treating the un-bolded letters as roman numerals and the hyphens as subtraction signs, and translating to decimal, you get the numbers on the left.  Using those as codes for unicode characters, you get the list on the right.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Number} && \text{Unicode character}\\
V && \text{V}\\
013C && \unicode{x013C}\\
004D && \unicode{x004D}\\
0395 && \unicode{x0395}\\
E && \text{E}\\
1E6A && \unicode{x1E6A}\\ 
024C && \unicode{x024C}\\
0041 && \unicode{x0041}\\
0045 && \unicode{x0045}\\
24D8 && \unicode{x24D8}\\
24C9 && \unicode{x24C9}\\
R && \text{R} \\
\end{align}
$$

> Anagramming the letters **VLMEETRAEITR** gives us **TIME TRAVELER**.
>
>  Thus you are a **time traveler** and you can go anywhere (anywhen?) you want to.